# Error when adding .css and other resource files to multiple Visual Studio projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to set up a solution in Visual studio that includes multiple web application projects, and I'd like to share .css files, master pages and other resources among the projects. I created a project to house the resources, then made links to the files within my web application project as instructed by the MSDN documenation, using "Add as link."

When I debug the project, I get the following error: "Copying file Site.css to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\Site.css failed. Could not find file 'Site.css'."

What am I missing? Is there a special Build Action that I have to set? I've done this successfully with .cs files before, so I'm not sure how this is different.

Edit: OK, I have partially figured out the issue. Apparently the linked files are included when I use Visual Studio's publish function to push the project to our development server. However, Visual Studio is not copying the file correctly when I hit F5 and run the project in the debugging server. Not sure why...

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue in VS 2005 (which may or may not work the same way as 2010) with a shared CSS file that in my project was added as a link. Running within the IDE wouldn't copy it to the correct directory.

With thanks to a tip on [this page](http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/usercontrols/usercontrols.aspx), I added the following post-build event command line (on successful build) which appears to have done the trick:

copy $(SolutionDir)\common*.css $(ProjectDir)\common\